# Bayesian modelling a player's score for a game broken up into separate rounds

Tags: regression, bayesian

I am trying to model a player’s score in a game. The game is broken up into 5 rounds, and their final score (S) is the sum of their scores in each round. (S = r1 + r2 + r3 + r4 + r5; all > 0).

I’m trying to set up this scenario as a Bayesian modelling problem where initially we come up with an initial prediction S - a prediction from a regression model based on other variables which influence the score (lets call them V1, V2, V3). This part is fine - next is what I'm not so sure about: I want to be able to use some sort of Bayesian sequential updating to update my prediction for S after each round.

So:

- Before the game, we use variables V1, V2, V3 to make a prediction for
  S
- After r1, we use the r1 score to update our prediction for S, also
  taking into account any changes in variables V1, V2, V3
- Repeat after r2, r3, r4, r5

I’ve been reading about Gaussian processes, Kalman filters, MCMC and other processes using Bayesian logic which seem like they would be applicable to my problem, but I’m not sure where to start regarding coding this up in Python or R.

I’d love some help with the any or all of following questions:

- Is there a name for the exact type of problem I’m trying to solve?
- How can I set up this problem using pymc3, Rstan or similar?
- Where can I find an example of a paper, blog post, whatever with somebody applying Bayesian modelling to a situation like this that will help me get started?

Answer (score 1):

I recommend modeling the incremental gained through the rest of the game to avoid correlation with the sums.  Here is one strategy which can be performed as a GLM or MCMC model in Stan:

Define: $S_i = \sum_{j = i}^5 r_j$

Fit 5 models:

$$S_1 = f_1(V1, V2, V3) + \epsilon$$
$$S_2 = f_2(V1, V2, V3, r_{1}) + \epsilon$$
$$S_3 = f_3(V1, V2, V3, r_{1}, r_{2}) + \epsilon$$
$$S_4 = f_4(V1, V2, V3, r_{1}, r_{2}, r_{3}) + \epsilon$$
$$S_5 = f_5(V1, V2, V3, r_{1}, r_{2}, r_{3}, r_{4}) + \epsilon$$

Prior to round 1:
$$\hat{S} = \hat{S_1}$$

after round 4, but before round 5:
$$\hat{S} = r_1 + r_2 + r_3 + r_4 + \hat{S_5}$$

In the `Stan` context, you would be doing this (pseudocode for linear regression, but you can use any GLM you want):

Calcs:

$$\beta_i V = \beta_{i,0} + \beta_{i,1} V_1 + \beta_{i,2} V_2 + \beta_{i,3} V_3$$
$$\theta_i r_i = \sum_{j=1}^i \theta_j r_j$$

Priors:

$$\beta_i \sim MVN(., .)$$
$$\sigma_i^2 \sim Gamma(., .)$$
$$\theta_i \sim MVN(., .)$$

Sampling:

$$S_1 \sim Normal(\beta_1 V, \sigma_1^2)$$
$$ ... $$
$$S_5 \sim Normal(\beta_5 V + \theta_5 r_5, \sigma_5^2)$$

You could also make this easier by fitting MCMC GLMs using `bayesglm` in the `arm` package in R.

Comment: Thanks for your answer - I'm going to try this approach. Going to keep the question open for a while to encourage some more discussion